# Programmatically Call go tests

Tags: testing, go

I want to run specific go tests that send http requests to a server with details on how the tests ran.

Is there a way to programmatically call go test [flags] within a go program?

**Super simplified example:**

```
func main() {
    results := runTests(identifier - packagename or testname)
    //send post request with results
}
```

perhaps I need to look into this http://golang.org/pkg/testing/#RunTests

Comment: Stop treating them as unit tests and just define methods and call those methods since you're already doing exactly that either way.

Comment: Or maybe just use `os/exec` to execute `go test` and capture output.

Comment: Or `go test` and any one of the multitude of available bash commands. Either way, choose the right tool for the job. Clearly you don't have that right now.

Comment: i noticed  `go-koans` just had a single test that called a number of functions that made assertions and exited:
https://github.com/cdarwin/go-koans/blob/master/setup_koans_test.go
not sure if that's what you had in mind

Comment: take a look at the testing package, it looks like you can run tests from a main entry point but I don't see the point in that IMO.

Comment: I think you are right @Not_a_Golfer I am going to have to dig into https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/go/test.go and https://github.com/golang/go/tree/master/src/testing and make sense of it. I will share my findings if no one gives a better answer :)

Comment: this gist gives a good example of how to do it: https://gist.github.com/vaskoz/98f2f1f0ec8f2cf0114c although it is said that the syntax could change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I decided to use exec to parse the output of the command to determine if the test passed or failed.

I am guessing one can look through the source code of some go testing framework like [GoConvey](http://goconvey.co/%20%22GoConvey) and maybe programmatically call a test and post the results. I will try this sometime in the future when I have more time HA.